# How to implement a Scrollbar on a list of Entry with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-entry

I am currently trying to make a scrollable list of entries using tkinter in Python 3. While looking for some documentation, I found this: [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter/3092341#3092341). It is really great and works really fine with Labels, but it doesn't seem to work with Entries. You'll find right here my code which creates a 2x25 list of entries through which I would like to be able to scroll:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, racine):
        super().__init__(master=racine)
        self.grid()

        self.entriesCanvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="white")
        self.entriesFrame = tk.Frame(self.entriesCanvas, background="white")
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.entriesCanvas.yview)
        self.entriesCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.entriesCanvas.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)
        self.scrollbar.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky='ns')

        # self.entriesFrame.grid()
        self.entriesCanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.entriesFrame,
                                         anchor='nw', tags='self.entriesFrame')
        # self.entriesFrame.grid()

        self.entriesCanvas.bind('<Configure>', self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.entries = []
        for i in range(50):
            self.entries.append(tk.Entry(self.entriesFrame, font=('arial', 30)))
            self.entries[i].grid(column=i % 2, row=i//2)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.entriesCanvas.configure(scrollregion=self.entriesCanvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    mainPage = MainPage(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Notice I commented two lines out. If you "activate" the first line, there will be a scrollbar and one can scroll through the entries, but it is strangely zoomed. On the other hand, if you "activate" the second line, the GUI will be as I would like it to be, but without the possibility to scroll, and it seems to show all entries (even if there are 1000 entries, therefore making a window which is 20 times the size of your screen).

Do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: You have to use `.create_window` therefore using `.entriesFrame.grid()` is wrong. Also remove all `.entriesCanvas.grid_...configure(...`. Read [How to get frame in canvas window to expand to the size of the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319445)

Comment: For the `.entriesCanvas.grid_...configure(...)`, it was part of a random test I was doing and I forgot to delete, so I've just updated the post.
However, I don't understand how not to use ´.entriesCanvas.grid()´. Does it mean I should use `.pack()` insted? I'm quite new with tkinter but it seemed to be a bad idea to mix `.pack()` and `.grid()`.

Comment: ***"bad idea to mix"***: Yes, will throw an error. Try to rephrase your problem and remove not relevant info like *"put two lines in comment"*

Comment: There should literally be no difference between using `Label` widgets and any other widget, including `Entry`.

Comment: You're right, the problem didn't come from the use of Entries instead of Labels, as it came from the size of my Entries (which are quite big as their font is Arial-30).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a way to have my program doing what I want. I just changed the method

```
def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    self.entriesCanvas.configure(scrollregion=self.entriesCanvas.bbox("all"))
```

by

```
def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    self.entriesCanvas.configure(scrollregion=self.entriesCanvas.bbox("all"), width=self.entriesFrame.winfo_width())
```

(I basically only added a parameter to ask the canvas to be the width of the frame.)
I don't know if it is perfect (as I still use .grid() istead of .pack()), but it works.

Thank you for giving me the source [Tkinter: How to get frame in canvas window to expand to the size of the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319445/tkinter-how-to-get-frame-in-canvas-window-to-expand-to-the-size-of-the-canvas), it really helped me find where my mistake was.

I truely apologise for my English, I know I make a lot of mistakes.