# Canvas frame doesn't extend to window size in Tkinter Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a frame using canvas for scrolling since I have added multiple buttons inside that frame. but the problem is when I make the `tkinter` window maximized the frame doesn't fill to the window size even though I have `fill=Both`.
([what my gui looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9rn.png))

```py
frame_a = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame,borderwidth=2,relief="solid",bg="#FFFAF0")
frame_a.pack(side="top",padx=1,pady=1,fill=BOTH)
```

when I remove the `scrollable_frame` which was created in canvas and replace it with the root window of `tkinter` then it expands to the window size when maximized.

I'm new to python, can someone please explain why it's not fill the window under frame created by Canvas.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

def open_link(link):
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open(link)

#create main window
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.geometry("1200x700")
main_window.title("Bookmarks")
main_window.configure(bg='#FFFAF0')

#Main label
label1 = tk.Label(main_window, text="Welcome", font='Calibri 20 bold',fg='#00008B',bg='#FFFAF0').pack()

#Create A Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(main_window,bg="#FFFAF0",height=50)
canvas.pack(fill= BOTH)

#create a frame to contain the scrollable content
scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas,bg="#FFFAF0")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

#Create a Scrollbar to the Canvas
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_window, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
scrollbar.pack(side="bottom",fill=X)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#Creating Style for buttons
style = Style()
style.configure('W.TButton', font =
               ('calibri', 12, 'bold'),
                background = '#000000',
                foreground = '#00008B')


style.map('TButton', foreground = [('active', '!disabled', 'green')],
                     background = [('active', 'black')])


#create frames
frame_a = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame,borderwidth=2,relief="solid",bg="#FFFAF0")
frame_a.pack(side="top",padx=1,pady=1,fill=BOTH)

label1 = tk.Label(main_window,bg='#FFFAF0').pack()

label1 = tk.Label(main_window,text="Prashant", font='Calibri 20 bold',fg='#00008B',bg='#FFFAF0').pack()

#Frame B
frame_b = tk.Frame(main_window,borderwidth=2,relief="solid",bg="#FFFAF0")

frame_b.pack(side="top",padx=1,pady=1, fill=BOTH)

label1 = tk.Label(main_window,bg='#FFFAF0').pack()
label1 = tk.Label(main_window,text="Varia", font='Calibri 20 bold',fg='#00008B',bg='#FFFAF0').pack()

#Frame C
frame_c = tk.Frame(main_window,borderwidth=2,relief="solid",bg="#FFFAF0")

frame_c.pack(side="top",padx=1,pady=1, fill=BOTH)


#create buttons with colors and links for Frame a - DPS Forward
button_data = [(frame_a, "A", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a,"B", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a,"C", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "D", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "E", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "F", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "G", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "H", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "I", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "J", "www.example.com"),
(frame_a, "K","www.example.com"),
(frame_a,"L","www.example.com"),
(frame_a,"M","www.example.com"),]

#For loop to iterate through links and button
for frame, text, link in button_data:

    button = ttk.Button(frame, text=text, command= lambda l=link: open_link(l),style='W.TButton')
    button.pack(side='left',padx=5,pady=5,expand=True)


#create buttons with colors and links for Frame b 
button_data = [(frame_b, "A", ""),
(frame_b,"B", "www.example.com"),
(frame_b, "C", "www.example.com"),
(frame_b, "D", "www.example.com"),
(frame_b, "E", "www.example.com"),
(frame_b, "F", "www.example.com"),
(frame_b, "G", "www.example.com"),
(frame_b, "H", "www.example.com"),]

#For loop to iterate through links and button for CAPS
for frame, text, link in button_data:

    button = ttk.Button(frame, text=text, command= lambda l=link: open_link(l),style='W.TButton')
    button.pack(side='left',padx=5,pady=5,expand=True)


#create buttons with colors and links for Frame c

button_data = [(frame_c, "A", ""),
(frame_c,"B", "www.example.com"),
(frame_c, "C", "www.example.com"),
(frame_c, "D", "www.example.com"),
(frame_c, "E", "www.example.com"),
(frame_c, "f", "www.example.com"),
(frame_c, "G", "www.example.com"),]

#For loop to iterate through links and button for HAPS
for frame, text, link in button_data:

    button = ttk.Button(frame, text=text, command= lambda l=link: open_link(l),style='W.TButton')
    button.pack(side='left',padx=5,pady=5,expand=True)

#label1 = tk.Label(main_window, text="CAPS Links", font='Calibri 20 bold',fg='#00008B',bg='#FFFAF0').place(x=890,y=130)
quit_button = ttk.Button(main_window, text="Quit", command=main_window.destroy,style='W.TButton')
quit_button.pack(side='bottom')

# Scroll bar
scrollable_frame.update_idletasks()
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [MRE].

Comment: I've added the code. Please assist

Comment: I've also added picture of the output

Comment: Have you tried adding `expand=True` ?

Comment: @Rory yes expand=True also doesn't work

Comment: When you resize the window, just the canvas is resized but not the frame `scrollable_frame`. So the frame `frame_a` will not be resized as well.  You need to resize the width of `scrollable_frame` when the canvas is resized.

Comment: Check this post out, It should have everything you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319445/tkinter-how-to-get-frame-in-canvas-window-to-expand-to-the-size-of-the-canvas

Seems like you could do something along these lines:


`def expand_frame(event):
 print(event.width)
`
and then bind this method to your canvas
`canvas.bind("<Configure>", expand_frame)`

The code for the function probably won't be exact but it should give you a clue

Answer (score 0):

When you resize the window, just the `canvas` is resized but not the frame `scrollable_frame`. So the frame `frame_a` (inside `scrollable_frame`) will not be resized as well. You need to resize the width of `scrollable_frame` when the `canvas` is resized:

```py
# save the item ID of scrollable_frame
frame_id = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
# resize the width of scrollable_frame when canvas is resized
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=e.width))
```

Comment: Thank you! This kind of solves the problem but creates another one. If I add more buttons to frame_a then the scroll doesn't work and crops the additional buttons

Comment: @prashantvaria Then you need to find a way to save the *width* after adding more buttons and use that *width* to determine the proper width to be set when the canvas is resized: `canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=max(frame_width, e.width))` where `frame_width` is the *width* after adding more buttons.